# A method of combining serialization with grammar parsing?

Tags: c#, parsing, serialization

I've come across a dilemma. My C# app uses a custom file format that needs to be human-editable in a text editor, but can also be editable via the GUI in my app. This file would represent a top-level object (call it TopObject), which contains several smaller objects, which in turn contain other objects, and so forth. All of the data contained in these objects is provided in the file.

I'm stuck as how to go about the issue of loading/saving these files. C# serialization doesn't work for me, as it breaks human-editability (binary serialization) or has "issues" with serializing collections of base classes (XML and DataContract serialization, which add text to disambiguate derived classes when serializing a base class, which makes the files more brittle to human-editing); if it weren't for needing to have the files editable by hand, it would have been the ticket. I've been looking into parser generators such as GOLD and GPLEX/GPPG to parse and convert the file into the objects they represent, and it looks promising, but this only covers the one direction of loading files, not ensuring they're saved in a correct format when writing them out.

What would be great would be a way to specify a grammar that handles both:
1) Reading a file with a specified structure and converting it into a TopObject and all its contained objects, and
2) Given a TopObject, writing its state out to a file with that same structure.
Pretty much, a single grammar that enforces import structure as well as enforces output structure.

Are there any such tools or frameworks that could help me? Is this something feasible, or am I overthinking this way too hard and there's an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would still use XML, but just write your own serializer. You could use the XML reader/writer classes in .Net to create a simple XML format:

```
<TopObject>
    <SubObject>
        <SubObject>
            etc.
        </SubObject>  
        <SubObject>
            etc.
        </SubObject>
    </SubObject>
    <SubObject></SubObject>
</TopObject>
```

I don't know if you consider this human-readable enough, but it's better that the stuff the .Net serializer creates. It would be easy enough to read/write recursively.

**Example:**

Here is a simplistic example that you can adapt. Assume I have this class:

```
public class Node {
    public Node(String _SomeProperty) {
        this.SomeProperty = _SomeProperty;
    }

    public String SomeProperty;

    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
}
```

Each `Node` has a property, called `SomeProperty`. It can also have children; more `Nodes` in the `Children` property.

Here is the `main` from a Console application that creates some data out of this class to serialize:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Make some data for testing
    Node baseObject = new Node("This is the base class");

    List<Node> Children = new List<Node>(){
        new Node("This is a child"),
        new Node("This is another child")
    };

    baseObject.Children = Children;

    Node aSubChild = new Node("This is a child of a child");
    baseObject.Children[0].Children = new List<Node>() { aSubChild };

    // Serialize

    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml");

    writer.WriteStartDocument();


    RecursivelySerialize(ref writer, baseObject);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

It calls a method called `RecursivelySerialize`, which does that actual work:

```
private static void RecursivelySerialize(ref XmlWriter writer, Node sc) {
    writer.WriteStartElement("Node");

    writer.WriteElementString("SomeProperty", sc.SomeProperty);

    if (sc.Children.Count > 0) {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Nodes");

        foreach (Node scChild in sc.Children)
            RecursivelySerialize(ref writer, scChild);

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

This method isn't complex. To improve it, you could use Reflection to dynamically serialize any type of class. Here is the output I got (formatted nicely) when running the above code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node>
    <SomeProperty>This is the base class</SomeProperty>
    <Nodes>
        <Node>
            <SomeProperty>This is a child</SomeProperty>
                <Nodes>
                    <Node>
                        <SomeProperty>This is a child of a child</SomeProperty>
                    </Node>
                </Nodes>
        </Node>
        <Node>
            <SomeProperty>This is another child</SomeProperty>
        </Node>
    </Nodes>
</Node>
```

Comment: @SimpleCoder, could you give a trivial example of a custom serializer?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't dwell too much on making the file human-editable, at least not editable by non-technical humans.  If an app needs to consume the file, then it will need accuracy, and no matter what kind of grammar you establish, humans will *still* get it wrong.

XML/JSON/INIs are still hard for some technical people to not mess up (surprisingly), but at least they're familiar to some techies.  I think those are better choices than rolling your own grammar.  Better yet, if you want to make editing the file more user-friendly, you could consider dropping the "human-editable" requirement and make it so it's only editable by an application.